# iTextSharp PdfSignatureAppearance.Close() throws Out of Memory Exception

Tags: c#, pdf-generation, itext, digital-signature

I have a application that digitally sign PDF files.

But I can't digitally sign a file bigger than 400mb in my developer machine.

I use the following code to sign. This code throws an OutOfMemoryException when call the method `Close` of `PdfSignatureAppearance`.

With smaller files it just works ok.

What can I do to avoid Out of Memory, when I need to sign big files?

Here is my code :

```
    private static void ApplySignatureDictionary(PdfSignatureAppearance sap, byte[] pk)
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] outc = new byte[8092];

            PdfDictionary dicSignature = new PdfDictionary();

            Array.Copy(pk, 0, outc, 0, pk.Length);

            dicSignature.Put(PdfName.CONTENTS, new PdfString(outc).SetHexWriting(true));
            sap.Close(dicSignature); //This throws a OutOfMemoryException, for files bigger than 400mb
        }
        catch (OutOfMemoryException omEx)
        {
            throw new Exception("Not enough memory to sign the file.", omEx);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Where `pk` is the result of `Org.BouncyCastle.Cms.CmsSignedData.GetEncoded()`

EDIT :

I instantiate PdfReader and PdfStamper this way :

PdfReader :

```
 PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(new iTextSharp.text.pdf.RandomAccessFileOrArray(inputPDF), null);
```

and

PdfStamper :

```
MemoryStream mFile = new MemoryStream();

PdfStamper stamper = PdfStamper.CreateSignature(reader, mFile, '\0');
```

Comment: How exactly do you instantiate the `PdfReader` and `PdfStamper`? Depending on that the memory use may differ greatly

Comment: @mkl I edited my question and added how I instantiate it. Thks

Comment: You might want to try using a `PdfStamper.CreateSignature` which requires a temp file parameter and supply a non-null one. This should reduce the resource hunger of the signing process a bit. I'm a bit surprised, though, that that happens during `Close`, not during `PreClose`...